# Is there a methodical way to desig multi-stage anti-aliasing filters?

Tags: circuit-design, simulation, active-filter, bode-plot

Lately I've been thinking about the best approach to design multi-stage anti-aliasing filters in real-life. I know tools like [Analog Filter Wizard](https://tools.analog.com/en/filterwizard/) or LTSpice can help to a certain extent, but they've got their limits.

For example, one problem I recently faced was the conversion of the following 8-pole filter (conveniently designed in the Analog Filter Wizard above):

SIGNAL IN - buffer - 4x sallen-key - buffer - SIGNAL OUT

to

SIGNAL IN - RC - buffer - 3x sallen-key - RC - buffer - SIGNAL OUT

to reduce the required opamp count and therefore PCB surface area. One would say that the RCs only need to replace the pole(s) that corresponded to the 4th (non-resonating) sallen-key. However after simulating the result, due to unidealities and stuff the resulting frequency response will be slightly off. And there comes my struggle with 2 things:

1. Simulator tools (that I know of) produce bode plots that are not interactive[^1] and therefore fine-tuning the filter is very tedious, and basically requrie a trial-and-error approach.
2. Resistor/capacitor values are quantised so even if I find the perfect combination of 8 resistor and 8 capacitor values by hand, chances are high that the required components will not be readily available.

Obviously, as you further increase the order of your filter, the fine-tuning of the frequency response becomes increasingly complex with too many variables. You need to turn resonance in certain stages to your advantage to achieve better roll-off, while maintaining an acceptable passband ripple, etc...

Does anybody know of a methodical approach that would help me in situations like this? I could not find good answers anywhere on the internet that deal with higher order analog filter designs, but it's possible that I was just not looking at the right place.

[^1]: By this I mean that I cannot move individual poles around in the picture that feeds back to the circuit and changes the passive values accordingly.

Comment: The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore it has been moved to chat and should be continued there (link below). --- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once, any further comments posted here which try to discuss / clarify the question, might be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat, please!** When someone has got enough information from the chat to post an answer, then please do that. Any factual updates to the question which are decided during the chat, should be made via an edit to the question as usual. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127391/discussion-on-question-by-davidanderle-is-there-a-methodical-way-to-desig-multi).